# Invariant subspaces for this linear extension of operators

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let $(e_k)$ be a total orthonormal sequence in a separable Hilbert space
>   $H$ and let $ T: H\to H$ be defined at $e_k$ by
>
> $T(e_k)=e_{k+1}$ , $(k=1,2,\cdots)$
>
> and then linearly and continuously extended to $H$. Find invariant
>   sub-spaces.
>
> Show that $T$ has no eigenvalues.

I know that the answer is $X_n=\operatorname{span}\{e_n,e_{n+1},\dots\}$are invariant subspaces which I got from E.Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis book. But I can't understand that how to prove the result. Also I'm unable to find any clue to prove the second result.

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: do you need all invariant sub spaces ?

Answer (score 3):

Assume $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. We have $x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_ie_i$, where $x_i = \langle x,e_i\rangle$. Let us start with $\lambda = 0$. Then $Tx = 0$. Hence,
$$
0 = T\sum_ix_ie_i = \sum_i x_iTe_i = \sum_i x_ie_{i+1}.
$$
But this implies $x_i = 0$ for all $i$ and so $x = 0$. Can you do a similar "trick" when $\lambda\neq 0$?

Comment: Thank You.. I got the ans about eigen value, but what about the invariant subspaces?@ Friedrich Philipp

Comment: Sorry, I corrected this. But yes, the "trick" is applicable.

Comment: Yes... I checked it out... It's applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately, concerning the invariant subspaces I cannot help you. I tried, but... I am sure one has to use that $T$ is isometric, but I don't know how. Maybe also that $T^*$ is the left shift (while $T$ is the right shift) and that $M$ $T$-invariant implies $M^\perp$ $T^*$-invariant. Actually, it is sufficient to prove that $e_n\notin M$ implies $e_n\in M^\perp$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that you spaces are invariant by $T$, in fact If we put $S_k=\overline{Vect\{(e_i)_{i\geq k}}\}$ then $S_k$ is a closed subspaces of H and for all $x\in S_k$ it exist a sequence $(a_i)_{i\geq k}$ of complexe numbers in $l^2$ such that :
$$
x=\sum_{i\geq k} a_i e_i \qquad (x=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots))
$$
Then 
$$
Tx=T\left( \sum_{i\geq k} a_i e_i\right)=\sum_{i\geq k} a_i Te_i=\sum_{i\geq k} a_i e_{i+1} \qquad (x=(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots))
$$
This Operator is called unilateral Shift. the set of all invariant subspace (Latices of sub-spaces) is known using the theory of complex functions, and it's called [Beurling–Lax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beurling%E2%80%93Lax_theorem)